# What is the safe and best-practice approach to a Firebase-based Payments/Credits system?

Tags: security, authorization, firebase, payment, credits

I have a question regarding my Firebase setup, with respect to security and practicality.

The goal is the enable a user to purchase credits, and spend those credits one by one. To enable this, I set up a "*users*" object where I store user-data (name, address etc.), a "*transactions*" object where I store all the purchases (amount, time etc.), and a "*spendcredits*" object where I store the data connected to the user spending a credit (time, on what, etc.).

Since the App must know how many credits the user can still spend, I created a variable in the user-object called validCredits, where the current available credits should be stored.
The user has read+write rights to his own user-object within "*users*" and read+write rights to his own object within "*spendcredits*". Only a different server has read+write rights to the "*transactions*" object.

So what happens is, the user purchases 5 credits. The server updates his validCredits variable with +5. The user spends a credit (-1), spends another (-1) and purchases 5 more credits (+5). His new validCredits amount is then 8.

I'm not sure whether this is a safe/optimal setup. I'm afraid that since a user has write rights to his own account, where the "*validCredits*" variable is stored, it might somehow be possible for him to add extra credits by increasing this value? Or can that be prevented by only allowing the user a "-1 credit" operator on this field?

I can also imagine that you might want to store everything in the "*transactions*" object, and just do a sum of all transactins when the App request the latest number of valid Credits? What is generally recommended for such a system with payments and credits?

Comment: This is a great question. How about a bit of clarification:  Are you using Firebase Rules for verification or is it App based? What type of login authentication are you using? What platform is this?

Comment: You can use security rules to enforce a user only decreasing their `validCredits`. That said, this question is far too broad for SO.

Comment: @AnidMonsur Can you post an answer of an example security rule that would enforce a user to only decrease their validCredits? It's a good answer and would provide a possible solution to the initial question.

Answer (score 1):

The following rule can be used to enforce that a user can only decrease their `validCredits` by one at a time. I'm assuming that you have some way of distinguishing the server from a user, which is what `auth.isServer` represents.

```
{
  "users": {
    "$uid": {
       validCredits": "auth.isServer || newData.val() === data.val() - 1"
    }
  }
}
```